# Incorrect context within $on in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm attempting to handle http errors within AngularJS (using ui-router), but am losing the context of my run function in the following code.

```
bugtracker.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
    //at this point $state and $rootScope are defined
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        //at this point $state and $rootScope are undefined
    });
}]);
```

The code that causes $stateChangeError to trigger is as follows.

```
//main.js
bugtracker.config(['$stateProvider', '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider', function($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider) {
    //...
    $stateProvider.state('projects.show', {
        url: '/{projectId:[0-9]{1,8}}',
        templateUrl: '/assets/projects/show.html',
        controller: 'ProjectShowCtrl',
        resolve: bugtracker.controller('ProjectShowCtrl').resolve
    });
    //...
}]);

//ProjectShowCtrl.js
projectShowCtrl.resolve = {
    project: function(Project, $q, $stateParams, $state) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        Project.findById($stateParams.projectId, function(successData) {
            deferred.resolve(successData); 
        }, function(errorData) {
            deferred.reject(errorData); // you could optionally pass error data here
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    delay: function($q, $timeout) {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
        return delay.promise;
    }
};
```

I would like $state to be defined within the anonymous function called by the $on function so that I could redirect the user to a 401, 403, etc. page, but I'm unsure why it is not.
In other examples I have seen (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/898) it is implied that $state is defined within the context of the anonymous function.

If anyone could explain why $state is not defined or what I can change to make it defined I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: There's no way these would be undefined, unless they were already undefined in the run block. However I've seen cases where the debugging tool thinks some variables are undefined when they actually aren't. That happened to me in FireBug with an old FF version.

Comment: Regardless of angular, what you are claiming violates the javascript language.

Comment: I completely agree, however, I've been debugging this for the past few hours and I can say with complete certainty that they are undefined. As a side note, `this` within the anonymous function is `window`. This may be normal; however, I would have expected it to be `$rootScope`.

Comment: @plalx Submit your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct! It must've been a bug within the Chrome debug tools because I tried writing what I wanted (`$state.transitionTo('error.401')`) and it worked! I can't believe it, thank you!

Comment: @ScottMielcarski Great, I'm glad that was it and `$rootScope` would have been `this` only if the library was designed that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way these would be undefined, unless they were already undefined in the run block. However I've seen cases where the debugging tool thinks some variables are undefined when they actually aren't. That happened to me in FireBug with an old FF version.

Comment: Just had the same problem with Chrome debugging tools (v44)